# Как обратить произвольный MemoryStream в строку и обратно?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, кодировка

Нужны надежные функции преобразования:

```
MemoryStreamToString();
StringToMemoryStream();
```

То что делал я работает не всегда. Для сравнения использовал .ToArray():

```
var array1 = originalMemoryStream.ToArray();// byte[726]
var array2 = restoredMemoryStream.ToArray();// byte[1333]
bool isEqual = array1.SequenceEqual(array2);//false
```

Тут восстановленный стрим не идентичен оригиналу. А бывают ситуации когда идентичен. Нужен способ который не подведет.

Пробовал разные кодировки вставлять в StreamReader/StreamWriter. При Encoding.UTF8 массивы разной длины как и раньше.. При new UTF8Encoding(false), особых изменений нет.
При Encoding.ASKII массивы из стримов одинаковой длины(обычно 726), но массивы разные, а строка такой же длины как и массивы. Заметил в массиве из восстановленного стрима много значений "63" - это знаки вопроса в ASKII.

Comment: Что-то странное у вас с данными. Приведите фрагмент тестовых данных, на которых "восстановление" не работает

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, опсал подробнее. К сожалению не могу дать пример таких данных, так как они из контекста (

Comment: Достаньте данные из контекста и выведите в лог. Или в отладчике посмотрите. Без  конкретного примера - будет только гадание. Может у вас там вообще не строка лежит в оригинальном массиве байт, или кодировка не та - тогда да, будут расхождения - не любой массив байт является валидной строкой :)

Comment: "не любой массив байт является валидной строкой" - не понял особенности проблем преобразования. К сожалению не могу скинуть полностью, но вот что есть (1-превью строки) https://prnt.sc/20viito, (2- visualizer для этой же строки) https://prnt.sc/20vi89n, и (3 - то что показывает консоль для этой же строки) https://prnt.sc/20vinpn

Comment: @John выглядит как UTF-8, раскодированный с помощью одномбайтовой кодировки. То есть как я и сказал, неверная кодировка при преобразовании в строку.

Comment: @aepot, передавал new UTF8Encoding(false) в конструктор по твоим заветам. Это проблема на этапе раньше или я просто что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @John всякое может быть, насквозь ваш проект отсюда не видно.

Comment: добавил не большое обновление, не знаю это имеет значение или нет

Comment: Запрос производит валидный JSON внути body для клиентского запроса

Answer (score 0):

Найдены подобные вопросы с ответом, который решает задачу:

(1) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801761/converting-stream-to-string-and-back-what-are-we-missing

(2) -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517771/memorystream-to-string-and-back-to-memorystream-without-adding-any-bytes-encod

Но не разобрался почему все именно так работает, поэтому лучшего ответа на этот вопрос еще нет.